# deleting same letter from input when writing to output java

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'd like some help with a problem I have in the following code.

```
package piglatin;
public class asdg {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "fifteen";
    int vowelSpot =  findFirstVowelPosition(word);
    String wordBeg = "";
    String wordEnd = "ay";
    String wordNew = "";

    System.out.println(vowelSpot);

    wordBeg = word.substring(0,vowelSpot-1);

    System.out.println(wordBeg);

    word = word.replace(wordBeg,"");

    System.out.println(word);

    wordNew = word + wordBeg + wordEnd;

    System.out.println(wordNew);
}


public static int findFirstVowelPosition(String word)
{
     int vowelPosition = -1;
    word = word.trim();

    for(int i=1; i <=word.length(); i++)  
     {      
        if ((word.charAt(i-1) == 'a') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'A')
         ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'e') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'E')
         ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'i') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'I')
         ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'o') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'O')
         ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'u') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'U')
         ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'y') ||(word.charAt(i-1) == 'Y')){
           vowelPosition = i;
            return vowelPosition;
         }
     } 
     return vowelPosition;
}
}
```

The purpose of this code is to take the string Word and put it in piglatin. Word will start with a consonant. The problem I'm having is when the string contains a specific consonant, then the first vowel, and the same consonant, it'll get rid of the second consonant.

This specific code isn't for homework, however I'll be applying this to a homework assignment.

Comment: well, what consonant is it failing on?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: Also, you `.trim()` in your method and return the position in the trimmed input. Why do I suspect this will lead to bugs?

Comment: Every consonant. Words like fifteen, didn't, and lol.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it:

Replace this line:

`word = word.replace(wordBeg,"");`

with

`word = word.replaceFirst(wordBeg,"");`

Check the documentation on it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html